# How to give value to {{form.as_hidden}} with a value from that html page

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-templates

```
<table align="center" >
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
    {% for c in ads %}
        <tr><td>{{c.Name}}</td><td>{{c.Address}}</td><td>{{c.City}}</td>
            <td><form action = "/" method = "post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_hidden}}
                <input type = "submit" value = "Delete">
            </form>
            </td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

How do I give `{{c.Name}}` as value to {{form.as_hidden}}?

```
def delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = deleteform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = add.objects.get(Name = form.cleaned_data['Name'])
            instance.delete()
        return HttpResponse(form)
else:
    form2 = deleteform()
    return render(request, 'MainTable/displayvariable.html', {'ads': ad, 'form2' : form2})
```

I'm trying to pass c.Name into my views.py file above.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The form is not rendered. Just submit `c.*` as POST? Maybe creating the form with `c.*` with python before passing it to the html?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to sumbit c.* as post, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use some hidden fields inside the form with the `c.*` values:

```
<form action = "/" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_hidden}}

    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value={{ c.Name }}>
    <input type="hidden" name="Address" value={{ c.Address }}>
    <input type="hidden" name="City" value={{ c.City }}>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Delete">
</form>
```